# Offline / Local Website with configuration options

Tags: html, web, local, offline, kiosk

thanks in advance for your time to help me.
So... I work on a Retail store and we use a kiosk-like app on the laptops with the hardware and price information.
Recently i realized (because it runs 24/7) the lcds are getting burned by the kiosk app and its a major problem to the store.

Since i cannot make changes on the app itself i realized the best option was to create some kind of solution to this problem.

So i thought on creating an offline / local website in HTML that mimics the layout on the kiosk app and use some kind of anti-lcdburn jquery running along. (**already have the code for the anti burn jquery**).

My main problem is the kiosk app was really **user-friendly** on the configuration. Anyone on my store could easily change the data showing.
But in the other hand if i want to implement a static html website, anyone without html skills can't easily change the values.

My first thought was to create some kind of config file and find a way to import it. My main issue it i need to make this so that anyone with low-it skills can enter a page , change values  and those values would show up on the kiosk page.

Something like a simple CMS but for a local file.

Any ideas?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Can you display the website inside an iframe?

If so, just make a file that loads the website in an iframe, with the anti screen-burn jQuery over the top.

Anything more than that would be overkill and rebuilding something that appears to already exist - have you considered asking the creator of the app to include an anti screen-burn option?